# NativeScript Version 8.2.1 : how to use old outdated plugins

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

> I am new to NativeScript and Webpack and i have migrated my native script app from 6.5.1 to 8.2 version, and i am using [nativescript-orientation-free](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-orientation-free) plugin ,i am getting build errors as this plugin still refers to tns-core-modules which is no longer supported in Native Script 8 and i am getting below errors

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free/orientation.js 17:12-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/enums' in '/Users/admin/Development/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free'

ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free/orientation.js 18:12-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/admin/Development/project/node_modules/nativescript-orientation-free'

we do not want to use this paid version  [pro-plugins-nativescript-orientation](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-orientation)

[image: orientation.js]

can you please let me know how can i fix this issue? is there anything i can do in the webpack.config.js ? I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed this plugin and able to set the orientation without any third party plugins using

```js
UIDevice.currentDevice.setValueForKey(1, "orientation");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have my sympathies.  (A quote from the movie Alien.)

Migrating a NativeScript app from 6.5 to 8.x can be wildly frustrating due to all the breaking changes. Make sure you watch this video: [Migrating Legacy NativeScript 6 Project to 8](https://youtu.be/7y6q2AeD73E).

When Migrating my app I found I had to migrate several of the plugins I used.  [Patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) is your friend!  To answer your question, you'll need to revise the links you circled.  Sometimes this is easy, sometimes this requires investigation.

These three should work:

```
import { Application as application } from '@nativescript/core';
const Enums = require("@nativescript/core/core-types").Enums;
import { Frame as frame } from '@nativescript/core';
```

I expect these two should work, 'tho I didn't use them in my project:

```
import { Page } from '@nativescript/core';
import { View as view } from '@nativescript/core';
```

Good luck!